# Voltage Comparator resulting in low when I would expect high output

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, comparator

I am playing with Voltage Comparators and finding my results are not as I would expect.

This is my circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6N9HX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I would expect in my circuit that my LED would light, because the voltage across the inverted input 1 - is higher than the voltage at input 1 + - because that is connected to ground.

Obviously my assumptions are either wrong, or my wiring is wrong! Please help!

----------------Attempt 2 -------------------

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZdjYQ.png)</sup>

----------------Attempt 3 -------------------

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fswsPF.png)</sup>

In attempt 3 - the LED is lit continuously - irrelevant of the voltage applied at Input 1 -

Comment: try [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/198205/lm339-basic-operation). Your "second attempt" will fry the LM339 when it tries to pull the 6.3 V wire to ground.

Comment: Thanks the Photon. So I have taken that and tried to incorporate into my design.....please see Attempt 3 above.

Answer (score 3):

The LM339, like many other comparators, has an open-collector output.  The output is just the collector of an NPN transistor, which can pull the output pin towards ground, but cannot pull the output pin high.  If the output should be high, the external circuit must pull the output up.

If you connect the LED between V+ and the output pin, the LED will light when the output is low, and not light when the output is high.

Comment: Hi Peter - thank you for your continued support! So in this circuit, my output Pin will be high....but what does high mean if its not equal to the V +?

Comment: @RenegadeAndy, an LM339 cannot produce a high output. It can only produce "low" and "high impedance". It's up to you to provide a pull-up resistor so that "high impedance" becomes a high voltage.

Comment: Ah, ok, so what would I connect the pull up resistor to? The output pin, and V+? I don't really understand that -- can you edit my circuit to include the suggestion?

Comment: If the output is Low, the output transistor will pull the output pin to Ground.  Otherwise, it just "lets go" of the output pin. If the output of the comparator should be High, the external circuit can pull the output up to whatever voltage you (or the circuit) likes, as long as the voltage is not more than the specified Absolute Maximum voltage shown in the datasheet.

Comment: Ok Peter, the problem I have is the 'lets go' bit in my head. If i ignore my confusion, If I popped a 315 ohm resistor onto the output pin.....what would the resultant voltage be on the output?! V = IR, and I don't know the current, but I do know the resistor value because I would attach that. This is why I am struggling to understand this pull up resistor.

Comment: When the comparator "lets go" of the output pin, it does not draw any current through the pin (the output looks like an open circuit), so there is no voltage drop across the pull-up resistor - if the pull-up resistor is connected to +5 volts, the output pin will also be +5 volts.  If you just hang a resistor on the output pin, but don't connect the other end of the resistor anywhere, the voltage on both ends of the resistor will be zero.

Comment: Ok - so I have editted the original question to include my 2nd attempt, I put on a resistor, and hooked it up to the main power supply...which results in a lit...but very hot LED, all the time irrelevant on the other voltage being applied.

Comment: The top of the resistor should go to the positive supply, and the cathode of the LED should go to the LM339 output pin.  If R1 is 390 ohms, you should only have 14 mA through the LED, even with your incorrect "2nd attempt" circuit.  With that current, the LED may be slightly warm - definitely not "very hot" - check that you are really using a 390 Ohm resistor, and not a 39 Ohm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46389/discussion-between-renegadeandy-and-peter-bennett).